# Laravel session lost after multiple clicks with application running on ECS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-ecs

Working on ECS, we built docker image and push to ECR and used it to run an ECS Fargate task.

However, while using that web app, every time we clicked any element multiple times (which will cancel some requests), the cookie and csrf token changed and we lost that session and got redirected to login page. Does anybody have idea why that happened?

We tried to run the exact same image on local but there was no error.

We also tried to disable/enable stickiness in ALB even though it didn't matter (only 1 task)

We do have similar laravel applications with same nginx config but they work well.

Sorry I can't provide example. The architect is simple: route53 > ALB (with SSL termination) > ECS service.

Edit: I only lose the session when I cancel requests using multiple click or manual cancel. The web worked fine if I just clicked and waited.

Comment: This would be a common issue if you are running more than 1 task behind the load balancer. Are you sure you aren't running 2 or more tasks?

Comment: @MarkB There was only 1 running task, and we tried to enable stickiness in target group and in ALB but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Configure ALB to use Sticky Sessions

Comment: I already tried, the question stated that.